# Binding XML file to a UserControl

Tags: wpf, xml, data-binding, user-controls

I want to bind the data from my XML file to my userControl.

So far I have:

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<testData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <pumps>
        <pump>
            <speed value="1200"/>
            <color value="Black"/>
            <heightAndWidth size="50"/>
        </pump>
    </pumps>
</testData>
```

App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="testDataDataSource" Source="Desktop\testData.xml" d:IsDataSource="True"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

UserControl:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Fill="{Binding XPath=color}" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="line1" Text="{Binding XPath=speed}" />
</Grid>
```

And MainWindow.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource testDataDataSource}}">
    <local:RectangleControl  DataContext="{Binding Mode=Default, XPath=/testData/pumps/pump}" />
</Grid>
```

However binding is not working. Could you point out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath isn't returning the attribute that contains the value you're trying to bind to.  Try this instead:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Rectangle x:Name="rect" Fill="{Binding XPath=color/@value}" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="line1" Text="{Binding XPath=speed/@value}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Right! I forgot that it's an attribute! Thanks.